# Structured reference in VBA to a specific row and range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iterate through a `ListObject` and, depending on whether a row is visible or not, select certain columns of that row to copy and paste into another sheet. I currently have the following code:

```
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterBudget")
For r = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If tbl.ListRows(r).Range.RowHeight <> 0 Then 'not hidden/filtered
        tbl.ListColumns("Item description").DataBodyRange(r).Select                   
        Range("[@[Item description]:[Unit 3]]").Select '<-- problem line                   
    End If
Next r
```

It does get to the right item, but I for some reason can't figure out how to select that particular set of columns (from item description through unit 3). What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` notation only makes sense when entered in a cell that is inside the `ListObject` in question.

From code, you already have rows and columns you want, so the cells you want is an intersection of the two:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim ColumnsOfInterest As Range
Dim r As Long

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterBudget")
Set ColumnsOfInterest = tbl.DataBodyRange.Worksheet.Range(tbl.ListColumns("Item description").Range, tbl.ListColumns("Unit 3").Range)

For r = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If tbl.ListRows(r).Range.RowHeight <> 0 Then 'not hidden/filtered
        Dim RangeToCopy As Range
        Set RangeToCopy = Application.Intersect(tbl.ListRows(r).Range, ColumnsOfInterest)

        RangeToCopy.Copy ...
    End If
Next r
```

Note that you [don't have to `select` anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

Comment: Both responses solve the issue, but this one is a bit cleaner to read.

Comment: GSerg, realised my range is non-contiguous for ColumnsOfInterest (skips the second column) - any suggestion on how to combine both a first column, then cols 3-10, in that variable?

Comment: great! I used this thanks to that method 3:
   
  `Set ColumnsOfInterest = Application.Union(tbl.ListColumns("Item description").Range, tbl.DataBodyRange.Worksheet.Range(tbl.ListColumns("Unit cost (VND)").Range, tbl.ListColumns("Unit 3").Range))`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most elegant but dealing with structured ListObject table references rarely are.

```
Dim tbl As Object, r As Long

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterBudget")

For r = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If tbl.ListRows(r).Range.RowHeight <> 0 Then 'not hidden/filtered
        tbl.ListColumns("Item description").DataBodyRange(r).Select
        ActiveSheet.Range(tbl.ListColumns("Item description").DataBodyRange(r), _
                          tbl.ListColumns("Unit 3").DataBodyRange(r)).Select
    End If
Next r
```

You could also use `tbl.parent` in place of `ActiveSheet`.